# Strict hyperplane separation of two disjoint convex positive cones

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Everything is in $\mathbb R^n$.

Consider two sets $A, B$ such that they are disjoint, convex, positive cones. That is, $\forall k > 0, kA = A, kB = B$.

Also assume that $B$ is closed and **polygonal**, and $A$ is relatively open.

I think it is true that there exists some hyperplane that separates them, that is strict on at least one side. That is, there exists some $p\neq 0$ such that $p \cdot A > 0, p \cdot B \leq 0$.

How to prove it?

Comment: Let $B=\{ (x,0) \mid x \ge 0 \}$ and $A= \{ (x,y) \mid x<0 \} \cup \{ (0,y) \mid y > 0 \}$. There is no strict separation.

Comment: I think the two new conditions should be able to make the result work.

Comment: Not chasing an evolving question.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a minimal counterexample in $\mathbb R^3$. $B$ is the closed cone $\{(x,y, z): x^2 + y^2 \leq z^2, z \geq 0\}$, and $A$ is the positive cone of $\{(x,y,z):x = z, y\in (0, 1), z > 0\}$.

The obvious fix is to make $A$ open, but this is just a general result: if $A, B$ are disjoint and convex, $A$ open and $B$ closed, then there exists such a separation. The "conic" property is entirely unused.

If we also assume $B$ is polygonal, then perhaps something like "enumerate all facets" may work.